# set CommandButton to know which grid to manipulate

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I  have an AX 2012 form with an actionpaneTab containing one CommandButton:NewButton and one CommandButton:DeleteButton, but there are two grid in my form. Each grid has own datasource and has own tabpage.

My question is how can I tell to my two buttons which grid to manipulate ?

For now the two buttons only controls the first grid. So without creating for each grid an actionpaneTab  : how can i insert or delete a line in the second grid by pressing NewButton or DeleteButton ?

Now both button add/delete from two grid at the one time

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot!
An action pane should only control a single data source.

Copy the action pane control to appear above the second grid then change the DataSource property to the second data source. Change the Style property to make it less prominent (Strip), see form SalesTable how this is done.